# ERROR: missing data for column SQL state: 22P04 postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I am trying to import CSV file into the postgreSQL database table. But i am getting an error :

> ERROR: missing data for column "portion" SQL state: 22P04 Context:
>   COPY fooditems, line 2: "Chicken Curry,100,132,4.5,11.4,7.6"

SQLCommands i am using is :

```
create table FoodItems
    (Food_item      varchar(20),
     Portion        varchar(7),
     Calories       varchar(7),
     Carbohydrates  varchar(7),
     Protein        varchar(7),
     Total_Fat      varchar(7),
     primary key (Food_item));



COPY FoodItems (Food_item,Portion,Calories,Carbohydrates,Protein,Total_Fat) 
FROM 'D:\convertcsv.csv' WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

link for the html page: 
http://www.buzzle.com/articles/indian-food-calories.html

I need the data in table so that i can use it for back-end for an app.
I don't understand what seems to be the issue.

Hope someone can help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your CSV File ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the CSV file.To test just change `DELIMITER ';'` to `DELIMITER ','` and run your COPY Command

Ie.

```
COPY FoodItems (Food_item,Portion,Calories,Carbohydrates,Protein,Total_Fat) 
FROM 'D:\food.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```